# D3, retrieve the x position of a <g> element and apply multiple transform

Tags: svg, d3.js, transform

With D3.js I want to transform the `x` of a `group` many times (eg. by clicking a button a causing a transform for every click), starting from the current position of the group. Problem is *I can't retrieve the x of the group* and, even if I find it, I can't find any built-in function that lets me change the `x` of a group starting from its current `x`. Am I missing something important? It's very strange I can't get the `x` of an element added to an SVG "stage".

My code is the following (edited for Lars): I created the nodes the way you suggested me yesterday (cloning them).

```
var m=[5,10,15,20,25,30];

var count=0;

d3.select('svg').on("mouseup", function(d, i){

     count+=0.5;

     var n = d3.selectAll(".myGroup");

     n.each(function(d,i) {

        if(i!=0){
            // here I need to know the current x of the current n element but I 
            // can't get it
            // this causes error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"
            // var currentx = d3.transform(this.attr("transform")).translate[0];

            this.setAttribute("transform", "translate("+((100/m[i])*count)+",10)");

        }

     });

});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Getting and changing the position of a `g` element is relatively straightforward. For example like this:

```
var g = d3.select("#myG");

// get x position
var currentx = d3.transform(g.attr("transform")).translate[0];

// set x position
g.attr("transform", "translate(" + (currentx + 100) + ",0)");
```

Edit:

If you have a raw DOM element, select it with D3 first:

```
var currentx = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform")).translate[0];
```

Comment: Hi Lars, I updated the question to try to explain things better.

Comment: Lars, thanks very much: I thought `d3.selectAll(".myGroup")` caused the fact that inside the loop body `this` was identical to the result of your `d3.select(this)`

Comment: Is it possible to get a transform translate set with `.style()`? I need to match an animation set in Leaflet CSS, and using `.translate()` the animation is out of sync.

Comment: Yes. Use `.style("transform")`.

Comment: I think it is useful just to change position of g element just relative to itself. This method does not gives relative x position of g element relative to its parent element.

Comment: D3v4 "The d3.transform method has been removed." https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md