# Using d3 collision detection for dragover behaviour on SVGs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to apply dragover behaviours to a fixed SVG circle, when one of my d3 force layout nodes (also appended with SVG circles) is dragged over it.

I've found lots of similar questions online that seem to point to either using a library like svg.js or snapsvg - or simply customising the collision detection function that you can find here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298 (which is what I'm trying to do).

So far I have this...

```
function detectCollisionWithFixedSVGShape(alpha) {

        var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(my_nodes);

        return function (d) {

            var r = d.radius + radius.domain()[1] + padding,

            nx1 = d.x - r,
            nx2 = d.x + r,
            ny1 = d.y - r,
            ny2 = d.y + r;

            quadtree.visit(function (quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
                if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {

                    var xCoordinateOfFixedSVG = 40; //40 is the x-pixel distance of my fixed SVG circle
                    var yCoordinateOfFixedSVG = 343.75; //343.75 is the y-pixel distance of my fixed SVG circle

                    var xDistanceFromFixedSVG = xCoordinateOfFixedSVG - quad.point.x;
                    var yDistanceFromFixedSVG = yCoordinateOfFixedSVG - quad.point.y;

                    var actualDistance = Math.sqrt(xDistanceFromFixedSVG * xDistanceFromFixedSVG + yDistanceFromFixedSVG * yDistanceFromFixedSVG);

                    var radiusBetweenPoints = quad.point.radius + 30; //30 is the radius of my fixed SVG circle container

                    if (actualDistance < radiusBetweenPoints) {
                        console.log("you dragged over my SVG circle container");
                    }               
                }
            });
        };
    }
```

Which is called in my tick function in the usual way...

```
node.each(detectCollisionWithFixedSVGShape(jitter))
```

When I load the page and start dragging nodes and watching the console for the "you dragged over my SVG circle container" message, there is a point with a radius of roughly 30 pixels (correctly), which displays the message - but it is NOT at the fixed point I'm expecting (40,343.75).  It's actually at a point a hundred or so pixels further to the right of the page (something like 200, 343.75).

I guess it's obvious now that I've hit the problem, but collision detection is working in relation to the svg canvas only - so it's looking at 40, 343.75 in the context of my canvas, but missing the fixed SVG component which is actually inside a div outside of the canvas and taking up the first 150 pixels of the left hand side of the page.

That's all a long way of asking whether there's any way around this?  I can't include the fixed SVG container instead the canvas since it would be open to getting dragged/zoomed etc like all the other nodes.  Can anyone think of a suitable way to adapt the collision detection function to reference absolute page coordinates??

Huge thanks for any thoughts at all!

---

EDIT after comments from Lars and Cool Blue...

I'm trying to manually "untransform" - the nodes are affected by 2 g-elements...

-> single parent g element (with a translate x/y and scale[]) which encapsulates all nodes

---> child g elements (with only a translate) which exist for every node

So on drag, I'm calculating this...

```
var transformedParent = d3.transform(d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("transform")).translate;
                    var scaledParent = d3.transform(d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("transform")).scale;

                    var transformedChild = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform")).translate;

                    //parent g will be undefined until first drag event
                    if (transformedParent==undefined) {
                        transformedParent[0] = 0;
                        transformedParent[1] = 0;
                    }
                    if (scaledParent==undefined) {
                        scaledParent[0] = 1;
                        scaledParent[1] = 1;
                    }

                    var untransformedx = (transformedChild[0]*scaledParent[0]) - (transformedParent[0]);
                    var untransformedy = (transformedChild[1]*scaledParent[1]) - (transformedParent[1]);

                    console.log("Untransformed node x: " + untransformedx);
                    console.log("Untransformed node y: " + untransformedy);
```

But as soon as I drag the canvas, my computed "untransformed" calculations are way off - I feel like I'm missing something really basic now because this seems like it should be a simple calculation to untransform the node positions?

Comment: [The word cloud generator](https://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/about/) has an implementation of collision detection.

Comment: Thanks for the link Lars - hadn't seen that before.  The only problem with the demo under "Hierarchical Bounding Boxes" is that it's a relatively "simple" example where the SVG shapes are both within the same SVG canvas.  My problem is in trying to reference an SVG container outside of the canvas by using absolute page coordinates.

Comment: It'll certainly be much easier if you can have everything within a single canvas.

Comment: But I think I need to keep my SVG container outside of the canvas in a separate div so it's not affected by other behaviour attached to the canvas.  My other thought is that since "d3.event.x" returns the absolute position of the mouse at any point - maybe there's a way to work that into the computation of the quad.point.x and quad.point.y?  If not, I might just use d3.event.x/y itself and "assume" the user's mouse is in the direct centre of the node being dragged (which it won't be most of the time but will at least give an approximate affect!)

Comment: actually, that isn't a good solution - just been experimenting, and on node drag, d3.event.x/y can't be trusted as an absolute coordinate!  surely there's a way to get the absolute x/y of where a node is at any given moment during drag?

Comment: Maybe with `d3.mouse()` on the HTML body or something similarly high level?

Comment: Only other thought (based on your answer to another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275627/d3-retrieve-the-x-position-of-a-g-element-and-apply-multiple-transform).  Can I reverse engineer the transforms that my nodes have been through to get the absolute coordinate?  E.g. Is it possible to amend "var currentx = d3.transform(node.attr("transform")).translate[0];" so that it also resets any scaling that's been applied to the canvas?

Comment: You could check out [this interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGLocatable). The `svg` element has a method called `getTransformToElement` and the matrix has multiply and inverse methods. This should allow you to reverse any transforms on the element issuing the mouse events. There is a method on the svg elements called `ownerSVGElement` that you can start from.

Comment: Can you post a working example?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Cool Blue - I'm looking at the svg interface now, but in the meantime I edited the original post with my possibly naive attempt to just figure out the un-transformed coordinates myself.  Any ideas where I'm going wrong there?

Comment: I still don't see a working example, Can you post the completed HTML at least? It's a bit of a guessing game without that...

Comment: Sorry Cool Blue - took me a while!  Here's a basic outline of the problem - http://jsfiddle.net/upyrL1x8/1/  - the 3 circles on the left (defined in var containerDiv, and var containerData) are the areas I'm hoping to use to detect when a node is dragged over them.

Comment: Any ideas based on the fiddle I uploaded Cool Blue?  I feel like I might be tackling the problem from the wrong direction, but really can't think of a better alternative within the confines of dragging one svg circle onto another with d3